# How do i get acetic acid from vinegar?

Tags: organic-chemistry, everyday-chemistry, extraction, fuel

I'm trying to improve my rocket project, but, since the competition only allows the use of vinegar and sodium bicarbonate as its fuel, I had an idea of using the vinegar in a different way. My plan was to get the acetic acid from the vinegar and substitute it for the acetic acid, which is probably more efficient and powerful in terms of acceleration. So, for that, I have some doubts about how should I do it

Comment: You can concentrate it quite a bit with fractional freezing.

Comment: Wouldn't that be a cheating as *"the competition only allows the use of vinegar and sodium bicarbonate"* ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azeotropic distillation.

Example from this patent: [here](http://Acetic%20acid%20is%20difficult%20to%20separate%20from%20water%20by%20conventional%20distillation%20or%20rectification%20because%20of%20the%20close%20proximity%20of%20their%20boiling%20points.%20Acetic%20acid%20can%20be%20readily%20separated%20from%20water%20by%20using%20azeotropic%20distillation.%20Typical%20examples%20of%20effective%20agents%20are%20ethyl%20n-valerate%20and%204-methyl-2-pentanone.)

> Acetic acid is difficult to separate from water by conventional distillation or rectification because of the close proximity of their boiling points. Acetic acid can be readily separated from water by using azeotropic distillation. Typical examples of effective agents are ethyl n-valerate and 4-methyl-2-pentanone.